# Google map won't load when tested in application

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

I have created a project in which I am trying to use google maps.

The maps are shown fine in all desktop and mobile browsers, but when deployed in the Android Tablet the map section is blank in the app.

I debugged it and found that the request where I am trying to get maps i.e. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE` is not loaded.

Comment: Why you put your question into code sample?

Comment: Although your question is not so exact, i think that Ajax is your answer which wuill help you replace the current content of the page instead of moving to another page seeing white flicker while loading.

Comment: oh is it ..@Taron .. k .. :-) ..@Stefanos..do u mean replace existing page content with other one ? .. if so .. how can i get page 2 content in page 1 ? ..

Comment: If page 2 is a completely new html page, with a head that loads phonegap and all scripts again, then you will have the flicker while phonegap inializes. If this is true, you should consider writing you app as an SPA. Just google SPA for more info.

Comment: k .. i seen at some blogs that using android **hardwareAccelerated** attribute setting in manifest can resolve this issue .. i checked but to no avail .. is there any alternative in phonegap environment ? @UnchartedSpace

Comment: Is page 2 a completely new page which loads your scripts anew?

Comment: yes .. @UnchartedSpace

Comment: Then your going to have a flash pretty much no matter what. You're unloading and reloading the entire Dom content and waiting for PhoneGap to reinit. Look into Single Page Application development. I like AngularJS but there are many frameworks to help you.

Comment: close your browser and start again, to reflect changes in system time.  Hope you are changing system time for testing something, otherwise update your question with exact requirement.

Comment: @sabithpocker .. ya .. i tried closing & reopening browser too .. but still the same exists .. also i noticed that restarting the system works fine ...

Comment: @sabithpocker .. ny idea how to make that work during refresh .. or on  opening of new Browser ? .. am really stuck here badly ..

Comment: Please update your question with the OS and browser with version numbers. Before that explain why you want it on refresh, may be your requirement can be met in a better way.

Comment: @sabithpocker .. am using Windows 7 .. Safari 5.1.7 ... In the app .. the feature is like if the user moves from one timezone to other .. and changes the timezone in the device & logs in .. the updated timezone is not date & time is not detected by Date Object.These changes will work only if he/she restarts the device ...

Comment: @sabithpocker .. assume scenario where my app is running .. and user updates the timezone and comes back .. even if I refresh the page same  date & time info is available .. not the updated one .. i observed all these in Android Browser , Windows 7 SAfari 5.1.7 Browser , Iphone Browser ..

Comment: What do you see in LogCat when trying to run the app in the device?